# Xml background for android app

Tags: android, background

[image: background for android app]

I want to make a background xml for my android app same image i attach, but i don't know how to make it, please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this examples experiment and explore on yourself that you may learn :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <gradient
      android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:endColor="#808080"
      android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

Also try this.

```
<shape>
   <solid
      android:color="#449def" />
   <stroke
      android:width="2dp"
      android:color="#2f6699" />
   <corners
      android:radius="3dp" />
   <padding
      android:left="15dp"
      android:top="15dp"
      android:right="15dp"
      android:bottom="15dp" />
</shape>
```

Don't forget to place them on your drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

This way solved my need, but anyone have better way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"> 
        <solid android:color="#017db1"/>
     </shape>
</item>

<item android:top="1px">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
       <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
    </shape>
</item>


<item android:top="2px">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"> 
        <solid android:color="#017db1"/>
     </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you're an Android newbie developer.

Don't say app. When you are working with Android development that is based on Activities.

I'm assuming that you have a main Activity called MyActivity.java. In the onCreate method you have to add a line of code that tells the activity to use a custom layout, like:

```
setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
```

Then you have to create a layout xml in the folder /res/layout called my_layout.xml, containing at least a Layout component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/my_bg_image"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Notice the background property that make use of your custom image. This image must be saved in the /res/drawable folder in your project as my_bg_image.jpg.

That's a start. Keep improving.

Comment: The question is about `make a background xml for my android app` not to use an image as you have said here `This image must be saved in the /res/drawable folder in your project as my_bg_image.jpg.`

Comment: Thanks Alessandro Alessandra but i don't want to use image. I need a xml backgroud file

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. Should I delete it?